# Read Graphviz file .dot in R

Tags: r, rstudio, graphviz

I am trying to read [this GraphViz file .dot](http://emac.berkeley.edu/gridlabd/taxonomy_graphs/R1-12.47-2.dot) in R and obtain a matrix with relevant information. After reading the file I will work on the matrix to obtain the output in specific format (I've worked a bit with matrices in R before and that is work I want and have to do). Instead of trying to parse and analyze the file from scratch, I'm trying to use an R package to speed it up.

The file was originally a .glm file ([GridLab-D](http://www.gridlabd.org/)) converted through a ruby script to DOT file by Michael A. Cohen as he expains [here](http://emac.berkeley.edu/gridlabd/taxonomy_graphs/). I am interested in obtaining parameters like "pos" for every element.

The only package I've found (although I'm ok in working with any other R package) is {sna}, and the function is [read.dot{sna}](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/sna/docs/read.dot). That (in case it worked with the .dot files I want to work with) would only return the adjacency matrix, and I want to retrieve the additional information (especially the fields like "pos" for the different elements).

The code I tried (that even if worked I think it would not retrieve the rest of the fields but only the adjacency matrix) is:

```
library(sna)
myAdjMatrix<-read.dot("R3-12.47-2.dot")
```

That returns to my Data environment:

```
num [0 , 0 ]
```

What package(s) would you use to extract information from the .dot file? How would you approach this file reading work?

I'm willing to learn, read, look and work a new solution, hopefully with some of your expertise it will be faster.

Note: RStudio version 0.99.902

Comment: Removed my answer - I hadn't noticed that you had an example dot file in your question, and `agread` is not correctly reading in the node positions from this file

Comment: Thanks for the answer and your time, I had been trying to figure that out and I was unable to read them too, I thought it was me the one who could not get it.

Comment: Yes, I don’t know enough about it, sorry. I noticed the bounding box (`bb=` argument) is the same in the dot file and graph `g` in my example, but it does not get read in correctly using your dot file. This may be used internal;ly to rescale in some way (but I couldn’t work it out). I actually think this is worth asking at the bioconductor website, as this is where the authors, and many primary users are (please update here if you get an answer).

Comment: I [asked at the Bioconductor website](https://support.bioconductor.org/p/83837/) too. I will update if I get an answer

Comment: I found [this](https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/igraph-help/2012-01/msg00036.html), but it's not fully working, it combines `sna` and `igraph`.